# How to use ARRAYFORMULA to remove values that contain brackets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I am trying to write a formula that pulls all data from column A that  doesn't contain brackets.

**Source Data**
[image]

**Desired Result**
<sup>(no values containing brackets)</sup>
[image]

Comment: Please do not show screenshots but a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a subset of rows in a column or multi-column range with the `filter()` function. To use a condition like *"the text string in the row does not contain a specific character"*, you can apply the `search()` and `iserror()` functions, like this:

```
=filter(A1:A, iserror(search("[", A1:A)))
```

See [search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) and [iserror()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349).